# PulseSecure VPN not working on 16.04

Tags: vpn

I followed my school's directions to install PulseSecure VPN client. But I cannot get it to work. Here are the directions:

1. Under the JunOS Pulse Installers link, click on Installers and navigate to the Linux folder.
2. If using Ubuntu Linux:
   a. Download the `.deb` file.
   b. Download the `vpnCA.cer` file.
   c. Append the full contents of the `vpnCA.cer` file to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
   and save the file.
   d. Install the `.deb` package with: `sudo dpkg –i filename.deb`
   e. You can remove the `.deb` file once the package installs.
3. Run  this    command to  ensure  your computer   is  configured  with    the proper  packages    to support the  GUI version. This will  determine   what    is  needed  for packages    and will    install 
   them    on  your    system.

   ```
   /usr/local/pulse/PulseClient.sh install_dependency_packages
   ```

Am I missing something? Because the desktop icon displays on the launcher, but does not open. The command to connect from the terminal does not work either -

```
/usr/local/pulse/PulseClient.sh -h vpn.school.edu -u email-address \ -U https://vpn.school.edu -r Default_Users
```

Basically nothing happens.